# Clearcase UCM: Rebasing From Parent Project Causes File Loss In Integration View

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We've been moving from Base CC to UCM but it couldn't be done all at once. We did a clearfsimport from Base to UCM then created a Prod project based on a post-import baseline.

We've since created other Projects using the most recent baseline (Prod_1) from Prod. Recently, we had to bring in another 'Project' from Base to UCM. The newly imported project's baseline was delivered into the Integration stream of Prod.

This gives us something this:

- Prod *[Project]*

  - BL Prod_1 (created from initial Base -> UCM import) *[Baseline]*

    - Release_2      *[Project]*

      - BL Release_2_1 (Created from changes in Release 2) *[Baseline]*
  - BL Prod_2 (created from second Base -> UCM import) *[Baseline]*

In order to pick up the changes from BL Prod_2 in Release_2, we did an Advanced Rebase on Release_2_Integration and picked BL Prod_2. It completed and said we had no versions that required merging.

However, it looks like the existing Integration Stream was entirely 'overwritten' by BL Prod_2 and lost all of the changes currently in Release_2_Integration.

If you look at the version tree of the 'missing' elements, you can see that they are part of the baseline created in Release_2_Integration *after* the rebase, even those they are not in a freshly updated Release_2_Integration view.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the proper way to do this? I have a pre-deliver BL on Release_2 so I can easily create a new project based on that.

Would we be better off creating a single 'Application' project using (sub)streams for each release/work-effort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> We did a clearfsimport from Base to UCM

You don't always has to: you can create components in any vob (linked to an admin pvob)

> we did an [Advanced Rebase](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccteam_ucm_rebase.htm) on Release_2_Integration and picked BL Prod_2.

(Advanced rebase means CCRC, right?)

If that rebase isn't working as you want, the easiest way to troubleshoot and move forward is to create another project, that you rebase directly with the right baseline.

Comment: By Advanced Rebase I mean we rebased the Project but chose Advanced and picked the other baseline. The project didn't see that there was a new baseline on the Prod project, so we manually grabbed it. 
By another project, do you mean create a project w/ the new Prod BL and rebase using Release 2? Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @bcrook88 I mean creating a new project and rebase the empty integration stream directly with the right BL.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little slow. New empty project, rebase to Prod BL and then deliver the Release 2 changes in? Or reversed. The goal is to merge prod and the release.

Comment: @bcrook88 no, rebase directly with a BL which represents Release 2: on an Integration stream, you can rebase with a BL coming from any stream you want. But if you want to merge, then yes, a deliver of Release 2 in would be correct.

Comment: What we really need is to get the updated production code into our release code. Doing the rebase on the release integration stream and picking the newest Production stream is what caused issues in the first place. Doing a delivery from Prod into the integration stream of the release project resulted in a similar situation where the Release changes were lost. Thanks for your continued help....

Comment: We did a test where we delivered the prod baseline into our new release stream, but not directly into the Integration stream. We created a substream and delivered into that. At the end of the deliver operation, all of the files that are new in the Release stream were show as 'not-visible' and were skipped.

Comment: @bcrook88 It seems the deliver actually overrides what is in the release Stream. Rather than doing a deliver, I would consider a simple clearfsimport of your Prod Baseline into the release stream view: any modified file in prod would override the ones in the release stream, but at least any new files in release stream would still be there.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I think pulling those imported files into the Prod branch has caused Clearcase to think they are newer and overriding. I'm hoping that once we get more into a proper cycle this will be smoother.